# What does the "all" mean in "pip install -e .[all]"?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have seen in a project the code

```
pip install -e .[all,postgresql]
```

But don't understand why the "all" is here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+install+square+brackets

Comment: BTW, that's buggy -- it should be quoted as `pip install -e '.[all,postgresql]'`; without the quotes, if you have any files in your current directory named something like `.a` or `.l`, the `.[all,postgresql]` will be replaced with a list of matching filenames by the shell before `pip` is started.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I understand the usage of square brackets. I only don't know the usage of "all".  Obviously there is no package named "all".  And I could not get a clear answer from the other related questions.